# Related project deployed in WAR but its classdefs not found by servlet class

Tags: jakarta-ee

After hours of testing and googling cannot figure this out.

I used Eclipse (Luna and Mars) to create a servlet (here TestServlet for demoing) which uses a class in another project (TestBusinessClass). The related project is included for the deployment in the Web Deployment Assembly dialog. The related project's jar can be found in the WAR file:

```
C:\tmp>jar -tf TestService.war
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
WEB-INF/lib/TestBusinessLogic.jar
META-INF/
WEB-INF/
WEB-INF/classes/
WEB-INF/classes/mvu/
WEB-INF/classes/mvu/test/
WEB-INF/classes/mvu/test/TestServlet.class
WEB-INF/lib/
WEB-INF/web.xml
```

Here is the contents of the TestBusinessLogic.jar:

```
C:\tmp\TestService\WEB-INF\lib>jar -tf TestBusinessLogic.jar
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
META-INF/
mvu/
mvu/test/
mvu/test/BusinessLogicClass.class
```

Still, when running with J2EE preview or Tomcat, I get

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: mvu/test/BusinessLogicClass
    at mvu.test.TestServlet.doGet(TestServlet.java:31)
```

when calling the servlet.

From what I understand from the stuff I found on the web, jars in the WEB-INF/lib directory should be along the web app's class loader's search path automatically, with no explicit configuration. Am I right on this?

What have I missed?